# Can we integrate SAS University Edition to .Net?

Tags: .net, sas

I am planning to show SAS Analytics report in my .Net MVC project. Is it possible to integrate **SAS University Edition** to .Net so that i can show SAS Analytics report in an iframe.

Comment: You're probably asking at too high of a level here.  What is your SAS process doing - creating a static .html report that you want to then display?  Or are you wanting to have something interactive in .NET that drives a SAS process?

Comment: You may be able to by leveraging the Jupyter interface and the fact that the SAS kernel is on github. But this isn't just a plug a play idea.

Comment: @Joe I want to pass some input to SAS process. Then SAS process makes the report and i want to send these report to .Net view to display to user.

Comment: Oh, Jupyter kernel.  Gotcha.  That does seem possible, but it seems rather a round-about method.